Were the Nazis "real" Christians?
Well, I know this question sounds a bit provoking, but I want to collect reasons to refute that Christians can be Nazis as well.
I recently had a debate with someone who noted that the German population was overwhelmingly Christian at the time, concluding that the Nazi ideology could likely be seen to be Christian or at least compatible with Christianity.
While that statistic might be true on paper, the question here is whether the conclusion that Christians could also be Nazis can actually be made?
=> Were the Nazis "real" Christians?
If the answer is no, does that mean that the statistics used in the Wiki article paint an inaccurate picture of what a Christian is? How so?
One of the most intuitive arguments will probably be that Christians at the time that also were part of the Nazi ideology, were not "true" Christians. A possible counter to that is the No Scotsman Fallacy.
Can, and if so, how can the No Scotsman Fallacy be refuted in this case?
Since there is already a related question regarding the catholic perspective I am interested in the protestant perspective. Although I don't mind other or more general viewpoints.
Edit
Since the definition of "real Christian" has been expected:
For the scope of this Question, a real Christian is someone who:

practices the teachings of the Bible to the best of his ability
does not practice Christianity out of mere tradition, habit, or cultural peer pressure.
Does not apply syncretism to his belief

(Considering the discussion in the comments, I probably need to add, that culture and traditions that are generally viewed as Christian but have a pagan origin are not counted, as most people have forgotten that origin and still celebrate something like Christmas as a Christian tradition. Syncretism in this case is focused on beliefs and direct consequences in action from that foreign belief. E.g. the need to go into battle to get into Valhalla because Norse Gods exist, while also compassionately helping a person that was robbed and hurt, because that is how God said you should show love towards your neighbor.
So for all intents and purposes, let's say "obvious syncretism" that mixes beliefs that are either almost or directly antithetical to each other.)
In the scope of this question this is not a Christian:

A person that has faith (because that is difficult if not impossible to find out)
A person that is saved (because only God ultimately knows that for each specific individual)
A person who rewrites the Bible to fit his belief
A person who kills Christians for the reason that they are Christian
A person that only has a Church Membership

Just to make sure: The question is about whether we can call people that officially were Christian during the nazi era really Christian, given the atrocities committed by the Germans at the time. Since those people are now mostly dead, it is difficult/impossible to verify if a person had faith, meaning a relationship with God including receiving the Holy Spirit, etc. Therefore we have to make our conclusions from the actions taken by those people because those are recorded and recordable.

This can't be answered without knowing what a "real" Christian is. For instance, there are many denominations that believe that Catholics are not "real" Christians, so for them, a large part of Germany was non-Christian even before they became Nazis.

"Does not apply syncretism to his belief" — Germany is the source of many ancient traditions that have made their way into the common practice of Christianity. Christmas for example has hanging stockings, advent calendars, Christmas trees, yule logs, holly and ivy, etc. They have taken on Christian meanings, and most Germans consider them to be essential parts of their Christianity, so (for the purpose of this question) are most Germans considered non-Christian?

@Ray whether or not anyone "considers [hanging stockings] to be an essential part of their Christianity , I never heard that they can be derived from Christ's teachings. Such things are clearly injected from other cultures, not native to Christianity.

@Conrado says "injected from other cultures, not native to Christianity". Exactly, that's the definition of "syncretism". The Question says "a real Christian is someone who: … does not apply syncretism to his belief", and since most Germans do have syncretism as part of their belief, they are not (by the OP definition) "real Christians". So, by the OP's own definition, most Nazi's are already excluded from being "real Christians".

ok, I didn't think of traditions and culture being syncretistic. Is kind of tricky as culture can also be seen as neutral, especially by ones that live in that culture. Never thought of Christmas as something non-Christian, although I knew that Christmas as Germans typically celebrate isn't necessarily of Christian origin. So let's focus on more contradictory ideas, beliefs and practices.

@Ray Errr--yes, you're right, that is the definition of syncretism. I wasn't paying proper attention; sorry.

In The Rise and Fall of the Third Reich, William Shirer wrote:

… under the leadership of Rosenberg, Bormann and Himmler — backed by Hitler —the Nazi regime intended to destroy Christianity in Germany, if it could, and substitute the old paganism of the early tribal Germanic gods and the new paganism of the Nazi extremists.

Given that one goal of the Nazi party was to eliminate Christianity itself (especially because of its Jewish roots), it would be difficult for a "real" Nazi to also practice Catholicism (or Lutheranism or other form of nominal Christianity).
On the other hand, aware of this situation, the Catholic Church often cooperated with the Nazis in order to continue its existence.
Even after the war, many high ranking Nazis were assisted in escaping to South America by members of the Catholic Church (see Ratlines (World War II)).

Were the Nazis "real" Christians?
The true and authentic Nazis were not Christians. However the masses under the Nazis regime could still be considered Christians.

Adolf Hitler's religious beliefs have been a matter of debate; the wide consensus of historians consider him to have been irreligious, anti-Christian, anti-clerical and scientistic. In light of evidence such as his fierce criticism and vocal rejection of the tenets of Christianity, numerous private statements to confidants denouncing Christianity as a harmful superstition, and his strenuous efforts to reduce the influence and independence of Christianity in Germany after he came to power, Hitler's major academic biographers conclude that he was irreligious and an opponent of Christianity. Historian Laurence Rees found no evidence that "Hitler, in his personal life, ever expressed belief in the basic tenets of the Christian church". Ernst Hanfstaengl, a friend from his early days in politics, says Hitler "was to all intents and purposes an atheist by the time I got to know him". However, historians such as Richard Weikart and Alan Bullock doubt the assessment that he was a true atheist, suggesting that despite his dislike of Christianity he still clung to a form of spiritual belief. - Religious aspects of Nazism

I do not see anyway the we could possibly consider true and authentic Nazis to be Christians, especially when they were so involved in the occult, antisemitism, anti-Christian, and desiring the restoration of pagan Germanic gods. The average German probably was unaware of what the upper classes within Nazism was trying to do or what they genuinely believed in.

Occultists who worked for the SS
Karl Maria Wiligut
Of all the SS personnel, Karl Maria Wiligut could be best described as a Nazi occultist. The (first?) biography of him, written by Rudolf J. Mund, was titled: Himmler's Rasputin (German: Der Rasputin Himmlers, not translated into English). After his retirement from the Austrian military, Wiligut had been active in the 'ariosophic' milieu. Ariosophy was only one of the threads of Esotericism in Germany and Austria during this time. When he was involuntarily committed to the Salzburg mental asylum between November 1924 and early 1927, he received support from several other occultists. Wiligut was clearly sympathetic to the Nazi Revolution of January 1933. When he was introduced to Himmler by an old friend who had become an SS officer, he got the opportunity to join the SS under the pseudonym 'Weisthor'. He was appointed head of the Department for Pre- and Early history within the Race and Settlement Main Office (Rasse- and Siedlungshauptamt, RuSHA) of the SS. His bureau could (much more than the Ahnenerbe) be described as the occult department of the SS: Wiligut's main duty appears "to have consisted in committing examples of his ancestral memory to paper." Wiligut's work for the SS also included the design of the Totenkopfring (death's head ring) that was worn by SS members. He is even supposed to have designed a chair for Himmler; at least, this chair and its covers are offered for sale on the Internet.
Otto Rahn
Otto Rahn had written a book Kreuzzug gegen den Gral "Crusade against the Grail" in 1933. In May 1935 he joined the Ahnenerbe; in March 1936 he formally joined the SS. "In September 1935 Rahn wrote excitedly to Weisthor [Karl Maria Wiligut] about the places he was visiting in his hunt for grail traditions in Germany, asking complete confidence in the matter with the exception of Himmler." In 1936 Rahn undertook a journey for the SS to Iceland, and in 1937 he published his travel journal of his quest for the Gnostic-Cathar tradition across Europe in a book titled Luzifers Hofgesinde "Lucifer's Servants". From this book he gave at least one reading, before an "extraordinarily large" audience. An article about this lecture was published in the Westfälische Landeszeitung "Westphalia County Paper", which was an official Nazi newspaper.
Rahn's connection of the Cathars with the Holy Grail ultimately leads to Montségur in France, which had been the last remaining fortress of the Cathars in France during the Middle Ages. According to eyewitnesses, Nazi archaeologists and military officers were present at that castle.
Gregor Schwartz-Bostunitsch
Gregor Schwartz-Bostunitsch was a radical author with German-Ukrainian ancestry. An active agitator against the Bolshevik Revolution, he fled his native Russia in 1920 and travelled widely in eastern Europe, making contact with Bulgarian Theosophists and probably with G.I. Gurdjieff. As a mystical anti-communist, he developed an unshakeable belief in the Jewish-Masonic world conspiracy portrayed in the Protocols of the Elders of Zion. In 1922 he published his first book, Freemasonry and the Russian Revolution, and emigrated to Germany in the same year. He became an enthusiastic convert to Anthroposophy in 1923, but by 1929 he had repudiated it as yet another agent of the conspiracy. Meanwhile, he had begun to give lectures for the Ariosophical Society and was a contributor to Georg Lomer's originally Theosophical (and later, neopagan) periodical entitled Asgard: A Fighting Sheet for the Gods of the Homeland. He also worked for Alfred Rosenberg's news agency during the 1920s before joining the SS. He lectured widely on conspiracy theories and was appointed an honorary SS professor in 1942, but was barred from lecturing in uniform because of his unorthodox views. In 1944 he was promoted to SS-Standartenführer on Himmler's recommendation.

Regardless if one was Protestant or Catholic, if a minister or priest opposed the Nazis regime, they faced both imprisonment and death. So much for being Christian!!!
It is truly conceivable that the average German did not know or understand the real Nazi ideology in Germany at the moment Hitler was in power.
High ranking Nazis were anything but Christian!

Nazi attitudes towards Christianity
Nazi ideology could not accept an autonomous establishment whose legitimacy did not spring from the government. It desired the subordination of the church to the state. Although the broader membership of the Nazi Party after 1933 came to include many Catholics and Protestants, aggressive anti-Church radicals like Joseph Goebbels, Alfred Rosenberg, Martin Bormann, and Heinrich Himmler saw the Kirchenkampf campaign against the Churches as a priority concern, and anti-Church and anticlerical sentiments were strong among grassroots party activists.
Hitler's Propaganda Minister, Joseph Goebbels, saw an "insoluble opposition" between the Christian and Nazi world views. The Führer angered the churches by appointing Alfred Rosenberg as official Nazi ideologist in 1934. Heinrich Himmler saw the main task of his SS organization to be that of acting as the vanguard in overcoming Christianity and restoring a "Germanic" way of living. Hitler's chosen deputy, Martin Bormann, advised Nazi officials in 1941 that "National Socialism and Christianity are irreconcilable."
Hitler himself possessed radical instincts in relation to the conflict with the Churches in Germany. Though he occasionally spoke of wanting to delay the Church struggle and was prepared to restrain his anti-clericalism out of political considerations, his "own inflammatory comments gave his immediate underlings all the license they needed to turn up the heat in the Church Struggle, confident that they were 'working towards the Fuhrer,'" according to Kershaw. In public speeches, he portrayed himself and the Nazi movement as faithful Christians. In 1928 Hitler said in a speech: "We tolerate no one in our ranks who attacks the ideas of Christianity... in fact our movement is Christian." But, according to the Goebbels Diaries, Hitler hated Christianity. In an 8 April 1941 entry, Goebbels wrote "He hates Christianity, because it has crippled all that is noble in humanity." In Bullock's assessment, though raised a Catholic, Hitler "believed neither in God nor in conscience", retained some regard for the organisational power of Catholicism, but had contempt for its central teachings, which he said, if taken to their conclusion, "would mean the systematic cultivation of the human failure". Bullock wrote: "In Hitler's eyes, Christianity was a religion fit only for slaves; he detested its ethics in particular. Its teaching, he declared, was a rebellion against the natural law of selection by struggle and the survival of the fittest."
As a measure in the struggle for power against the influence of the churches (Kirchenkampf), the Nazis tried to establish a "third denomination" called "Positive Christianity", aiming to replace the established churches to reduce their influence. Historians[who?] have suspected this was an attempt to start a cult which worshipped Hitler as the new Messiah. However, in a diary entry of 28 December 1939, Joseph Goebbels wrote that "the Fuhrer passionately rejects any thought of founding a religion. He has no intention of becoming a priest. His sole exclusive role is that of a politician." In Hitler's political relations dealing with religion he readily adopted a strategy "that suited his immediate political purposes."
Many Nazi leaders, including Adolf Hitler, subscribed either to a mixture of pseudoscientific theories, such as Social Darwinism, mysticism, and occultism, which was especially strong in the SS. Central to both groupings was the belief in Germanic (white Nordic) racial superiority. The existence of a Ministry of Church Affairs, instituted in 1935 and headed by Hanns Kerrl, was hardly recognized by ideologists such as Alfred Rosenberg or by other political decision-makers. A relative moderate, Kerrl accused dissident churchmen of failing to appreciate the Nazi doctrine of "Race, blood and soil" and gave the following explanation of the Nazi conception of "Positive Christianity," telling a group of submissive clergy in 1937:

Dr. Zoellner and [Catholic Bishop of Munster] Count Galen have tried to make clear to me that Christianity consists in faith in Christ as the son of God. That makes me laugh... No, Christianity is not dependent upon the Apostle's Creed... True Christianity is represented by the party, and the German people are now called by the party and especially the Fuehrer to a real Christianity... the Fuehrer is the herald of a new revelation.

Religion in Nazi Germany


We are all 'Nazis' in God's eyes. ...before having faith.
Romans 3:9-18

What then? are we better than they? No, in no wise: for we have before proved both Jews and Gentiles, that they are all under sin;
10 As it is written, There is none righteous, no, not one:
11 There is none that understandeth, there is none that seeketh after God.
12 They are all gone out of the way, they are together become unprofitable; there is none that doeth good, no, not one.
13 Their throat is an open sepulchre; with their tongues they have used deceit; the poison of asps is under their lips:
14 Whose mouth is full of cursing and bitterness:
15 Their feet are swift to shed blood:
16 Destruction and misery are in their ways:
17 And the way of peace have they not known:
18 There is no fear of God before their eyes.

The misconception in the question asked is that our sins make us sinners.  The truth is we sin because we are sinners at birth.
God is not damning Nazis for eternity because they deserve it.  We ALL deserve it.  It is when we recognize that truth, that we need a savior...from ourselves, that our new spiritual identity in Christ will begin to manifest upon placing our faith in Him.  We believe that God loves us, even though we are all sinners, and therefore gave us Jesus Christ as our means of becoming spiritually and eternally secure in Him.  It is because of His love for us all that by His grace, not our merits or lack thereof, that we are saved through having faith.  Did any of the Nazis have faith before or after their horrendous deeds?  Only God knows, but the believing 'Nazi' that we would be with for eternity would not possess any evil traits of their  carnal lives of this "present evil world" (Gal 1:4).
Romans 5:6

For when we were yet without strength, in due time Christ died for the ungodly.

It is not our corrupt carnal bodies that arrive in heaven with whoever else has believed in the gospel of God's grace. It will be our perfect, glorified, incorruptible spiritual bodies that will live forever.
1 Corinthians 15:53-54

For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.
54 So when this corruptible shall have put on incorruption, and this mortal shall have put on immortality, then shall be brought to pass the saying that is written, Death is swallowed up in victory.

